# Moving number to the end in an array

Tags: java, arrays

The code below I have set the midpoint of the array to five but now I want to move the midpoint to the very end and as it moves to the end the other numbers will go to the left to fill the gap. No arraylists aloud.

```
        int mid = length/2;

    for (int i = array.length-1 ; i> mid; i--) { 
        array[i] = array[i-1]; 
    } 
    array[mid] = 5;
```

Comment: @UmNyobe bring the midpoint to the end while shifting the other numbers in the array to the left

Comment: That code puts the number 5 in the mid point.. I don't really know why. When you say end, do you mean the last position in the array? As @Che said, what have you tried?

Comment: you need to have a `swapElement(int ndx1, int ndx2)` operation, this sounds like homework?

Comment: Sadly, by doing this person's homework for them after they kept posting it, people have encouraged the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
int mid = array.length/2;

for (int i = mid; i < array.length-1; i++)
{
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[i+1];
    array[i+1] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int mid = array.length / 2;
    array[mid] = 5;

    // my code starts here...

    int aux = mid; // aux isn't necessary if you can lost mid value
    int backup = array[mid]; // save the middle value

    for (; aux < array.length - 1; aux++) { //starting at middle until the end of array
        // current pos receives the next value;
        array[aux] = array[aux + 1];
    }

    array[array.length - 1] = backup; // restore the middle value at the end;
}
```

That code transforms [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] in [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5]. 
Is it that you want?